# Having an Issue Displaying from Database Using Select, PHP, FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm having an issue with displaying information from a database using a select statement in a FPDF file. I've created two files. The first file, the user inputs the DonorID and hits create invoice. The file points to the fpdf file that goes and creates a pdf file and displays an invoice. It has a select statement that doesn't seem to be generating any results. Everything else displays properly, but the table is not displaying any information from the database.

Here is the first file, called createinvoice.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> Create Invoice Page</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Create Invoice</h1> 
    <form action="invoicereportpdf.php" method="POST">
    <p>Create an invoice by typing in the Donor ID</BR>
    Donor ID: <input type= "text" name="donorid" size="15"/></br>

    <br>
    <div id="container" style="width:900px">
        <br>
        <input type= "submit" name= "submit" value="Create Invoice"/>

        <?php include '/html/includedonations.php'; ?> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the second file that is called by the first one called invoicereportpdf.php

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/');
require('mysql_table.php');

class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
    function Header()
    {
        //Title
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',14);
        $this->Cell(0,6,'Invoice',0,1,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
        $this->Cell(0,6,'From',0,1,'C');
        $this->Ln(12);
        $this->Cell(0,6,'Vetsports.org',0,1,'C');
        $this->Ln(14);
        $this->Cell(0,6, 'Thank you for your donation to Vetsports.org, your 
        donation is greatly appreciated.',0,1,'L');
        $this->Ln(16);
        $this->Cell(0,6, 'Please keep this receipt for your tax 
        purposes.',0,1,'L');
        $this->Ln(16);
        //Ensure table header is output
        parent::Header();
    }
}

//Connect to database
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('charitabledb');

$donorid=$_POST['donorid'];

$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AddPage();
//table: specify 4 columns
$pdf->AddCol('ID',15,'ID','C');
$pdf->AddCol('date',15,'Date','C');
$pdf->AddCol('donorid',25,'Donor ID','C');
$pdf->AddCol('firstname',25,'First Name','L');
$pdf->AddCol('lastname',25,'Last Name','L');
$pdf->AddCol('paymenttype',35,'Payment Type','L');
$pdf->AddCol('organization',30,'Organization','L');
$pdf->AddCol('Income',40,'Amount Donated','L');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select ID,date,donorid,firstname,lastname,paymenttype,organization,Income from donations where donorid="$donorid" order by date ',$prop);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: I do believe that it has some thing to do with my select statement, because when I take off the where donorid="$donorid" It works with out an issue.

Comment: Right, so, I had the wrong quotes. Here's how I had to change my statement" ("select ID,date,donorid,firstname,lastname,paymenttype, organization,Income from donations where donorid= '$donorid'",$prop);

Answer (score 0):

Right, so, I had the wrong quotes. Here's how I had to change my statement" ("select ID,date,donorid,firstname,lastname,paymenttype, organization,Income from donations where donorid= '$donorid'",$prop);